# Meaning of "I'm sure you'll be able to tie with Jane."

Tags: meaning, word-meaning

The speaker's friend is not as good as the other contestant. And she is encouraging her to practise. Then she says this sentence.

> I'm sure you'll be able to tie with Jane.

I am confused if the speaker is certain that the contest would be a tie or is just giving hope to his friend.

Comment: Yes, hilariously, in English, people often say "I'm sure that..." exactly when they aren't sure.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on intonation. You can't tell just from the writing whether the speaker intends "I'm sure" as a certainty or just as optimism.

To analyze it another way, through the Gricean conversational maxims, "I'm sure" can be read as a hedge of the maxim of truth because it concedes that the information is subjective. Or, in plain English, "I'm sure" means you're saying it's your feeling, not a fact.

According to this reading, "I'm sure" is actually less certain. You can now guess which of these is more assertive:

> I'm sure you'll tie with Jane.

> You'll tie with Jane.